# How to drop/remove a published repo in aptly?

Tags: apt, repository, debian

This seems to be a prevalent issues which many are facing and there isn't a solution anywhere on the internet.

I create a repo with my .deb packages and it is published, now my release file in the repo is corrupted, so I need to fix the Release file, I want to drop the repo , but when I drop it, I get an error saying 'Published repos cannot be dropped' . How to unpublish a repo and drop it, so that I can create a new repo with same distribution and publish again.

Answer (score 3):

If I got you correctly, you've created local repo with `aptly repo create`, added some packages there and published it with `aptly publish repo`. aptly would refuse to drop local repo with `aptly repo drop` if repository is published. So you need to drop published first with `aptly publish drop`.

If the `Release` file got broken, you might just try running `aptly publish update` to re-generate metadata files.